# CallRail Webhook in PHP

Tags: php, webhooks

I am trying to set up a webhook from callrails platform. According to CallRail documentation it appears that my endpoint should response with a HTTP status code of 200? I've done webhooks before but never seen this one before. I am not getting anything after a call is made.

From call rails docs
"Your endpoint should respond with a HTTP status code of 2xx to indicate that the data was received properly. In general, a response status code other than 2xx indicates that the webhook was unable to complete the requested action."

This is the php code I am using. I just want to see the data being posted. Is there something I need to add to properly respond with 200 status code?

```
include('common.php');

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $msg .= 'Key: ' . $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br>';
    }

    $ret = runner_mail(array('to' => 'xxxx', 'subject' => 'Callrail Call POST', 'htmlbody' => $msg));


    $data = json_decode($_POST['body'], true);
    if(!empty($data))
    {
    
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $message .= 'Key: ' . $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br>';
        }
    
        $ret = runner_mail(array('to' => 'xxxxxx', 'subject' => 'Callrail Body Data', 'htmlbody' => $message));    
    
    }

}
```

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

for anyone that wants to know here is the answer.

```
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$call = json_decode($payload);
//process data 

http_response_code(200);
```